# NOde.js/Express App can't find some node_modules

Tags: node.js, express, path, sweetalert

I use several Node/Express modules in my app, and everything works fine for every module as long as I do `const module = require('module');`. I don't need to define a static path for these modules as `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`.

However, for the **sweetalert** module, if I define in my *layout.pug* (base pug file) `script(src="/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js")`, I get a 404 Error (not found) unless I include in *app.js* the following static path: `app.use("/node_modules", express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules"));`.

My question is: is this the normal behaviour or is it something I'm not doing right? (I'm kinda confused why I have to define a static path just for one of several modules I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's whats going on:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` is declaring that the public directory is accessible to the browser. You should put all your front end resources in that folder. This will help separate what can be accessed from the server and what can be accessed from the client.

When you reference `script(src="/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js")` the browser throws a 404 because that file is not located in the public directory, therefore off limits to the browser.

Adding this line `app.use("/node_modules", express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules"));` "fixes" your issue but now exposes all your node_modules to the browser. This probably isn't a good idea and I'm sure a security expert could elaborate why this shouldn't be done.

How I would resolve this issue: Go through your `.pug` code and look at any resources your front end requires. Then copy them over to the public folder and fix your references to use the copy of the resource.

Here's an example of a script I use to move resources from the node_module directory to a public/assets directory:

**build.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

const ASSETS = [
    'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js'
];

if (!fs.existsSync('./public/assets')){
    fs.mkdirSync('./public/assets');
}

ASSETS.map(asset => {
    let filename = asset.substring(asset.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    let from = path.resolve(__dirname, `./node_modules/${asset}`)
    let to = path.resolve(__dirname, `./public/assets/${filename}`)
    if (fs.existsSync(from)) {
        fs.createReadStream(from).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(to));
     } else {
        console.log(`${from} does not exist.\nUpdate the build.js script with the correct file paths.`)
        process.exit(1)
    }
});
```

then I update my package.json to include this in the scripts:

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node ./build.js || true",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

then in any of my views pages I reference the resource by using the new path

**random.pug:**

```
script(src="/assets/jquery.min.js")
script(src="/assets/sweetalert.min.js")
```

Finally before you deploy your app you now must run the following command:
`npm run build` then `npm start`

You will only need to run the build command if your front end resources change. So if you only ever use `sweetalert.min.js` you will only need to run the build the first time you run your app. If later on you add another resource `aNewResource.js` you will need to update the `build.js` file and run `npm run build` again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still have a long way to go to be able to understand all security issues and concerns.

Comment: One additional question: in my page, I want to provide wav files for listening in the browser, and ask the user some questions about it. To be able to access the json files where this is defined I'm using the same "recipe": `app.use("/definitions", express.static(__dirname + "/definitions"));
app.use("/sounds", express.static(__dirname + "/sounds"));
app.use("/answers", express.static(__dirname + "/answers"));`. My question is: is there a way to do this without exposing all this info to any curious user?

Comment: Just move anything you are planning to use in the browser to the public directory. So create a public/sounds directory. Unless there is some sort of access control reason for not exposing all files to the browser.

Comment: yes, there are some reasons for not exposing some content, as it's supposed to be a blind listening experiment...otherwise if some info is exposed, the answers will be biased

Comment: Access control: lets say you have file a that you only want to expose to a couple users, if you put that in the public directory anyone can access it by going to http://yourdomain/sounds/fileA.wav to prevent that you would put that somewhere else outside of the public directory then access media via a get call in routes/

Comment: This really helped me but I actually ended up using "path" in order to make it platform agnostic and then I also specifically directed it to only a single node module like this: ```app.use(
  "/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist",
  express.static(
    path.join(__dirname, "..", "node_modules", "socket.io", "client-dist")
  )
);```. Not sure if it is best practices but it appears to be working.